# Is using $GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS'] deprecated?

Tags: php, global, deprecated

I know that the use of [`$HTTP_GET_VARS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is deprecated but what about using [`$GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)? Is that array key likely to disappear in the future?

I basically have the following all over a legacy project that I need to integrate with a CMS and I don't really want to have to update it unless strictly necessary.

```
function table_manager_import_vars($var) {
   $vars = explode(",", $var);

   foreach($vars AS $var) {
       switch ($var) {
           case "G":
               $var = "HTTP_GET_VARS";
               break;
           case "P":
               $var = "HTTP_POST_VARS";
               break;
           case "C":
               $var = "HTTP_COOKIE_VARS";
               break;
           case "S":
               $var = "HTTP_SESSION_VARS";
               //session_start();
               break;
           case "E":
               $var = "HTTP_SERVER_VARS";
               break;
       }
       if (isset($GLOBALS[$var])) {
           if (is_array($GLOBALS[$var])) {
               foreach($GLOBALS[$var] AS $var1 => $value) {
                   if ($var1 != $var) {
                       $GLOBALS[$var1] = $value;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
// called like this
table_manager_import_vars("G,P,C,S,E");
```

And yes you guessed it there is a function like this for every aspect of the project just with a different name each time!!

Comment: As Ignacio alluded to, this function is a terrible idea.

Comment: They would only be available with `register_long_arrays=On` in the **php.ini** anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question:

> Is using $GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS'] deprecated?

Answer:

Yes it is.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

This page explicitly states that `$HTTP_GET_VARS` has been deprecated and you should use `$_GET` instead.

`$HTTP_GET_VARS` is the same thing as `$GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS']`. And therefore it is also deprecated for the reason. (note that all variables defined at the global scope can be referenced using `$GLOBALS['variablename']`)

By the way: When it comes to working with legacy code that uses `$HTTP_GET_VARS`, I know you said you want to avoid changing the code if you can avoid it, but it's worth pointing out that code of this age is likely to have big issues when run in a modern PHP installation, as older versions of PHP would have assumed things like `magic_quotes` being in use. If you run the same code in a newer version of PHP you won't have `magic_quotes`, so you should make sure the data is escaped properly.

Looking at the whole code that you've got there, it looks like it's trying to copy all the variables in the various `HTTP_***_VARS` arrays into the globlal scope. This is functionality that was done automatically in *really* old versions of PHP, but was dropped because it causes massive security issues. I seriously recommend dropping that whole bit of code and converting everying to use `$_GET` instead. You might want to [google for `register_globals`](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+promote+variables) for more info on why this is a bad thing.

Comment: You missed the point that the OP didn't know `$GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS']` and `$HTTP_GET_VARS` are one and the same.

Comment: @Tomalak - heh; yea, I'll add that in.  :-)

Comment: I agree with all these points, but due to the proliferation of this code all through the legacy project and the old enemy of budgets it is unlikely to be changed. This code is hidden behind a couple of layers of auth on an extranet so it is unlikely to cause too many issues from a security point of view.

Comment: @Treffynnon - Basically what you've got here is PHP4 code trying to emulate a PHP3 feature. Bringing this into a PHP5 system is going to give you some serious headaches - it's going to be a pain to get it working in the first place, maintenance is going to be an absolute bitch (trust me, I've been there when it comes to legacy PHP code!), and regardless of any other security layers, if this code is accessible on the internet, you will have security problems.

Answer (score 7):

`$HTTP_GET_VARS` and `$GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS']` are the same thing. `$HTTP_GET_VARS` is a **superglobal**, and superglobals can be (but don't *have* to be) accessed via `$GLOBALS`.

Also, that code is a huge security hole.

Comment: Actually `$HTTP_GET_VARS` is *not* a superglobal. `$_GET`, which replaces it, *is* a superglobal.

Answer (score 4):

They're the same.

`$HTTP_GET_VARS` *is* `$GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS']`, and as such "both" are deprecated in favour of `$_GET`.