# Updating deprecated Code

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using $GLOBALS['HTTP_GET_VARS'] deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044995/is-using-globalshttp-get-vars-deprecated)
>   [Invalid arguements in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561822/invalid-arguements-in-php)

I get the following response when I run script in a WAMP environment:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\GeCard\eCardScript_ecards\ecard_lib.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\GeCard\eCardScript_ecards\ecard_lib.php on line 21

This is my code:

```
function getPostGetVars() {
    global $HTTP_POST_VARS,$HTTP_GET_VARS;

    foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) {  //This is line 17
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
    }

    foreach ($HTTP_GET_VARS as $key => $value) {   //This is line 21
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
    }
}
```

I am told that this code is deprecated. Can this piece of code be easily updated to eliminate the warnings?

Comment: The answers you got when [you were told that explained how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561822/invalid-arguements-in-php)

Comment: Sorry, was not getting it and research was not helping, hense the reframed question. Item now resolved and script working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_POST` and `$_GET` instead of `$HTTP_POST_VARS` and `$HTTP_GET_VARS` respectively.

```
function getPostGetVars() {
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  //This is line 17
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {   //This is line 21
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
}
```

If you check the manual pages for [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), you'll see that their more verbose counterparts have been deprecated.

---

I can't help but notice what you are trying to do with this code essentially mirrors the function of [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/extract). I would caution you from doing this because an attacker could rewrite essential variables (say `$isLoggedIn`) with a request and exploit the server. If you continue to do something like this I suggest using [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/extract) with a flag such as `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` so that there are no collisions. You can prefix the get variables with `get_` and the post variable with `post_`, for example.

However, unless you truly know what you're doing, using extract like this (or your method) is ***extremely*** dangerous in a production environment. I would advise against it completely and instead use the proper super globals to access the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables.

See [this post by Marc B on this vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023799/568785) for more.

Answer (score 1):

This code basically does what `register_globals = on` does, just in a worse way (GET having priority over POST). You should completely remove this code and update the script to use the appropriate variable `$_POST['field']` or `$_GET['field']` to access POST/GET data instead of just using `$field`.

The reason why the code stopped working is that `$HTTP_*_VARS` were replaced with the `$_*` superglobals, so to fix it remove `global $HTTP_POST_VARS,$HTTP_GET_VARS;` and replace `$HTTP_POST_VARS` with `$_POST` (likewise for `$HTTP_GET_VARS`).

However, you can also fix it by completely removing the function and replacing the *call* to it with `extract($_REQUEST);` (assuming the function is always called in the global scope and not inside a function).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getPostGetVars() {
  global $_POST,$_GET;
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  //This is line 17
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {   //This is line 21
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use $_POST['variable_name'] instead of global $HTTP_POST_VARS and $_GET['variable name'] for $HTTP_GET_VARS